# Nhibernate / SQL Server: default lock mode

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate, transactions, locking

We are using NHibernate 1.x and SQL Server 2005 with default configuration.

What is default lock strategy in NHibernate? Is it "none" and all relies on SQL Server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the source, the default lock seem to be none.

[Look here](http://nhibernate.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/nhibernate/branches/1.2.x/nhibernate/src/NHibernate/Impl/SessionImpl.cs?revision=6038&view=markup) at row 2392.